# How to get a chain rule format of derivation when using Mathematica?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, derivative

I have plenty of functions,such as f1(x),f2(x)...fn(x), each one is quiet simple.
But when I nested them just as f1(f2(f3(...))), the whole function becomes really complex.

It nearly impossible to get the derivation of the whole function. 
How to get the derivation by the chain rule format.

Take an example:
There are plenty of functions defined as following:

```
Subscript[f, 0][x_] := x;
Subscript[f, k_][x_] := a^Subscript[f, k - 1][x] + b^Subscript[f, k - 1][x]
```

When I calculate the derivation of f5(x):

```
D[Subscript[f, 5][x], x]
```

It output a really complex formula. For this derivation, using chain rule is much more simple. The chain rule for each function can be this(similar form):

```
Subscript[df, 0][x_] = 1;
Subscript[df, k_][x_] := Subscript[df, k - 1][x] (Log[a] a^Subscript[f, k -1][x] + Log[b] b^Subscript[f, k - 1][x])
```

It get a same result, but much more simple. So how to make Mathematica output a result whose form likes: fn'(fn-1(x)) * fn-1'(fn-2(x)) * ...

Comment: you should ask this on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: Mathematica is an "Infinite Evaluation" system. That means it keeps evaluating things until the last evaluation didn't change anything. That also means it will try very hard to resist your desire for it to give you Sin'[Log[x]]*Log'[x]*x' instead of continuing until it finds Cos[Log[x]]/x. You can try to learn how to use Hold and other such functions to block the evaluation process, but this is often difficult to understand how to do.